# Which IDE tool can expediently convert .dll project (devolopped by VC) to .so project on linux platform

Tags: linux, visual-c++, dll, ide

I have a DLL project which is developped by VC++. Now I want to create a .so file on linux platform with the DLL project. How can I achieve it easily? Any IDE tool can help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In fact the answer will be useful even if the DLL does not have any original source code with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is written in cross platform c/c++ (=has no references to native Win32 API) you can probably just recompile the project on linux with gcc. You will have to create a makefile that would instruct gcc to build an so file for you on linux.